# How do I grab a count of all the documents in a firebase collelction in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have code that grabs the documents in a collection, but it seems to only grab 15 at a time(from what I seem to understand) and I was trying to use this list to determine the total number of documents in the collection for a program I'm creating. I need to be able to tell how many documents are in the specified collection from the start.

Here is the beginning of the code, where it is apparent that the limit that the var will register is 15 and then I can never get the accurate number.

```
getStatistics(): void{
    const visitArray = this.afs.collection("visits").snapshotChanges();

    //console.log([this.afs.collectionGroup("visits")].length);
    this.k = 0;
    for (let val of visitArray.toString()){
        this.k += 1;
        console.log(this.k);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the 'length' of the collection from the get-go? It is essential that I know the number of documents in the document from the very beginning.

I tried using the .get() command too and it returned the same initial number(15) of documents from the collection.

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually trying to count, and the answer doesn't clear it up for me.  The API does not provide a way to count subcollections nested under a document.  Your answer is counting something other than Firestore collections, perhaps the number of document fields?  Collections are containers for documents, and documents are containers for fields.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the process of what my code was actually doing. I have a collection that contains documents with IDs to help refer to other collections. I was talking about the highest level collections that the database holds when I actually should have been referring to the documents in the collection. So, while I could technically be correct with the original wording, I was not correct in what I was actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to subscribe to the initial pull of the collection's contents and then grab the length of that variable. So for me, I did:

```
const visitArray = this.afs.collection("visits").snapshotChanges();

    visitArray.subscribe(payload => {
        this.totalVisitCount = payload.length;
    });
```

Then the number of documents in the specified collection is stored in totalVisitCount.